# Saving photo to the remote server from the blackberry application

Tags: blackberry

Can any one please tell me the process through which I can open a photo gallery in the blackberry application to choose a photo to upload, is there any file uploading control in the blackeberry 5.0  and also tell me the process to save the photo from the blackberry application to the remote server using HttpWebRequest.

Thanks

Comment: How i would approach this problem is

1. Use a file picker control from samples
2. Choose a file
3. Convert the file to a byte array
4. Send the byte array across to the server

Answer (score 0):

Their is nice way which i have done. Just get selected image from the phone through file browser or file io method than convert it to a byte array than just encode it to base64 String and send this string to the server by http request.

and at server side just do opposite.

```
  final byte[] chunk;
           chunk = new byte[actualSize];
           try {
                        int bytesRead = in.read(chunk);

           fconn.close();
           } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();

                    }
           try 
           {
 String encodedStr = Base64OutputStream.encodeAsString(chunk, 0, chunk.length,false,false);

           }
```